# How to authenticate and invoke Google Cloud Functions via HTTP from Make.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth, make.com

As background: There is a huge gap in our org between technical and non-technical people. I've setup Cloud Functions that run via Cloud Scheduler, but we'd like to change the invocation to make.com. so non-techies can invoke whenever they need to. I'm looking for quick-fix that has an easy setup.

I understand that one can call Cloud Functions via HTTP, using a valid Bearer Token, but these expire after one hour.

From my search I've seen that one could do use JWTs, but this sounds kinda tedious using a no-code platform like Make.

Another option I'm trying right now is to make our services accessible via an API Key using API Gateway, but I'm afraid we would have to manage those on top of the existing Cloud Functions.

Maybe there is a way to access the Cloud Functions using the service accounts we already use?

Comment: Read how Cloud Function authentication/authorization is performed. The docs include examples. The only method Cloud Functions natively supports is OIDC Identity Tokens. Yes, you can creat those tokens from a service account.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @John Hanley

> Read how Cloud Function authentication/authorization is performed. The docs include examples. The only method Cloud Functions natively supports is OIDC Identity Tokens. Yes, you can creat those tokens from a service account.

In addition, take a look at these references:

- [Authenticate for invocation(Cloud Function)](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)
- [Methods for getting an ID Token](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/get-id-token)